# Google Sheet Report with CSV Repository on Google Drive > Update report when new CSV is added to repository

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-api-client

## I am building a script using the Google API that will append new CSV files to a Google Sheet Report.

### GDrive Layout:

- **Google Sheet**  = Accumulated Labor Report > Tab1 = Pivot Table, Tab2 = Data List
- **Folder** = CSV Repository > 7 Day Labor Reports

*Currently, the Data List is manually updated each week with the data on the new CSV file.*

### Process:

1. Web Application distributes SQL report as a CSV to Gmail account.
2. A time-triggered script runs saving the file to a CSV repository on Google Drive.
3. *A time-triggered script runs appending the new CSV data to the Data List
4. The new CSV file is renamed to include the date at the end.

#### *I need help with step 3 in the process.

I have tried different methods but the closest I have gotten is adding a new tab of data instead of appending the data.

The new tab was a result of:

```
var master = ss.insertnewdata();
```

### This is what I have so far:

```
  function importData() {

    // Folder ID of the repository containing all CSV files

    var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById("Folder ID");
   
    // CSV file name of the last recieved report file
    var weeklyreport = fSource.getFilesByName('Project Time Reporting.csv');
    
    // Google Sheet ID containing labor report and data list
    var ss = Sheet ID');

    // Data list tab on Google Sheet
    var dataListSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data List');
             
      // Last row on the data list tab.
    var lastRow = dataListSheet.getLastRow(); 
     // var ReportData =   
    

    
    if ( weeklyreport.hasNext() ) { // procced if CSV file name exists in the repository
      var file = weeklyreport.next();
      var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
      var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
               // loop through csv data array and append rows into Data List
      for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i+i ) {
        //After last row on data list, insert new row with all data from CSV.
    dataListSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
        
      }
      
      // rename the report.csv file so it is not processed on next scheduled run
      file.setName("Weekly Labor Report Export-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv");
}


    function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to COMMA.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp(
      (
        // Delimiters.
        "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

        // Quoted fields.
        "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

        // Standard fields.
        "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
      ),
      "gi"
    );

    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [[]];

    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;

    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

      // Get the delimiter that was found.
      var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

      // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
      // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
      // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
      // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
      if (
        strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
        (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
      ){

        // Since we have reached a new row of data,
        // add an empty row to our data array.
        arrData.push( [] );

      }

      // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
      // let's check to see which kind of value we
      // captured (quoted or unquoted).
      if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

        // We found a quoted value. When we capture
        // this value, unescape any double quotes.
        var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
          new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
          "\""
        );

      } else {

        // We found a non-quoted value.
        var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

      }

      // Now that we have our value string, let's add
      // it to the data array.
      arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return( arrData );
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `importData()` function, define a variable that will be the `Data List` tab:

```
var dataListSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data List');
```

Find the last row of the `Data List` tab:

```
var lastRow = dataListSheet.getLastRow();
```

Add the imported data to the row below `lastRow`:

```
dataListSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is adding the information to the Data List tab now but unfortunately now its returning with an error: **Execution failed: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 12**  *(line 28)* See updated script.

Comment: The error is preventing the .csv file from getting renamed.

Comment: You'll need to log the CSV array and inspect it to see why the script sees a mismatch in number of columns. Re the line to add the imported data to the sheet, you have placed that inside a loop. But that line posts the entire CSV array in one go. Inside the loop it just repeats the "paste" job.